# looking for a GPS device which can transmit the location directly

Tags: gps

I am looking for a `GPS` device or receiver that can transmit its own location to a specified configured server directly.

there will be no medium like mobile phone or computer in between GPS and Server which receives the data.

a dongle sort of thing which has a sim card in it and with the use of that it can transfer data directly to server

Comment: are you looking for a GPS tracker recommendation ?

Comment: yes , iam looking for tracker

Comment: 2 years ago i had made some researches for a GPS tracker without server service, i found this good tracker http://gpsgate.com/devices/meitrack_meiligao_mvt600 , i don't know if there is somthing better these days, you can take a look @ alibaba.com

Comment: do know anything about FLORA GPS chip ?

Comment: this is the first time i hear about it, if you are ready to make you own installation you can try ublox , it's widely used by UAV's community

Comment: what community is this can you tell me please

Comment: diydrones.com    .